# Eclipse showing build issue on cleaning and "build all"

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, build

After cleaning and "build all", i am getting this error in eclipse->Markers->Java problems

"The project cannot be built until its prerequisite platform is built. Cleaning and building all projects is recommended"

How to resolve it?

Also, this codebase is compiling perfectly fine on doing "ant all". If eclipse is showing compiling issue, then why is ant not showing a compiling issue

Comment: Go to build path of your project  and see what other projects are added there... Then go and build all the projects mentioned there... Then build the current project..

Comment: @TheLostMind : That's what i am doing. I run clean all, then build all.

Comment: I got the issue. You are right. If all its child projects will build fine then it will as well.